# React Admin - Cannot focus on an AutocompleteInput programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using React Admin and was trying to focus an AutocompleteInput but its not working for me. Sample code as follows

```
    const CreateFormCustom = (props) => {
      const fieldRef1 = useRef(null);
      const fieldRef2 = useRef(null);
      const fieldRef3 = useRef(null);
      return (
        <SimpleForm {...props} redirect={false} >
          <ReferenceInput helperText={false} fullWidth label="Users" source="u_id" reference="v1/users">
            <AutocompleteInput inputRef={fieldRef1} onSelect={() => {fieldRef2.current.focus();}} optionValue="u_id" optionText="u_name" />
          </ReferenceInput>
          <NumberInput inputRef={fieldRef2} source="t_qty" label="Quantity" helperText={false} onKeyDown={(e)=>{if(e.which==13||e.keyCode==13) fieldRef3.current.focus();}} />
          <NumberInput inputRef={fieldRef3} source="t_price" label="Price" helperText={false} onKeyDown={(e)=>{if(e.which==13||e.keyCode==13) fieldRef1.current.focus();}}  />
        </SimpleForm>
    )}
```

Other two fields focus working perfectly but when i am on last field and press enter it shows error that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null`

Comment: Can you try adding a `tabindex=0` to the AutocompleteInput?

Comment: Sorry, not working.

Answer (score 0):

The inputRef parameter is used inside the AutocompleteInput component and the passed parameter is ignored:
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/input/AutocompleteInput.tsx#L465

Comment: Currently i am passing like `options={{ InputProps:{inputRef: fieldRef1}}}`, It is kind of working but dropdown list does not show with that field but browser upper left corner. So you have any other better way to ref that field as that is important for me to focus programmatically.

Comment: Maybe try this: <AutocompleteInput autoFocus={state.autoFocus} ...

Comment: not autoFocus, i need to change focus programmatically.

Comment: You can try to control the component by changing the autoFocus property by condition